# Join DbSets with repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern

I have basic implementation of repository pattern with generic `IRepository<T>` which holds `Add`,`Remove`,`Find`, etc. and I have more precise repositories such as `IActorRepository` and `IFilmRepository` that derive from `IRepository`. I have a method for search box that finds top 5 actors and films that match text from the search box.

My question is how can I join these to repositories? I need my method to be testable, so I don't want `IQueryable` in my method, just an interface I can mock later on.

The only thing for me that comes to mind is to create some kind of helper class such as `public class FilmsActorsHelper: IFilmsActorsHelper`. I'm sure someone had an issue like that, what is a common practice here, how is it usually solved?

Method for which I need a solution:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchBoxChanged(string inputValue) {
    if (inputValue == null || inputValue.Length < 3)
        return Json(new List<string>());

    const int maxNamesCount = 5;
    var names = _filmRepository.Find(f => f.Name.Contains(inputValue)).Select(f => f.Name).Take(maxNamesCount).ToList();
    var remaining = maxNamesCount - names.Count;
    var actorNames = _actorRepository.Find(f => f.Name.Contains(inputValue)).Select(f => f.Name).Take(remaining).ToList();
    names.AddRange(actorNames);

    return Json(names);
}
```

Also, because I have `ToList()` I suspect it will pull everything from database, right?

Comment: `how is it usually solved?` <= By not trying to wrap a type that already implements a Repository pattern (`DbContext`) in your own Repository type(s). You are adding an unneeded abstraction that only makes your code more difficult to read and you have to jump through hoops to do simple things like joining tables. Create a service instead that has an instance of your DbContext and do your work in there and return a result. Consume that service from your Controller. Then you can join on whatever you want.

Comment: @Igor i haven't thought of that. It makes sense to create services instead of repositories. What about standard methods, such as `Add`, `Remove`, `Find`, etc.? Should I have a service for every DbSet or just keep my repositories? Could you show me an example of how these standard methods and more precise ones would work in services?

Comment: It should encapsulate and expose business logic. So if you want to return a list of films based on actor then you would have some method like `Task<List<Film>> GetFilmsForActorAsync(string actor)` that would do that. Do not try to wrap each entity in its own service, then you have added nothing of real value.

Comment: @Igor Ok, but if I need to add new `Actor` or `Film`, where should I do it then?

Comment: Same place. In some service. You can also split your services based on functionality and read/write. See [CQRS pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=cqrs+pattern)

Comment: @Igor I read a little bit about CQRS pattern and it seems to me it is more useful for saving state changes. I started implementing services instead of repositories and it really makes my life easier. The only thing that is really difficult is to find meaningful names for them. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you are referring to the CQRS pattern and the names of the services keep in mind you can reuse the same names but keep them in different name spaces. You could also use CQRS across interfaces and have the same type implement multiple interfaces. Using interface based programming (using IoC / DI) the controllers would then have the types injected into them and not have to know about the concrete type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not wrap a type that already implements a Repository pattern (`DbContext`) in your own Repository type(s). You are adding an unneeded abstraction that only makes your code more difficult to read and you have to jump through hoops to do simple things like joining tables. Create a service instead that has an instance of your DbContext and do your work in there and return a result. Consume that service from your Controller. Then you can join on whatever you want.

Services should encapsulate and expose business logic. So if you want to return a list of films based on actor then you would have some method like `Task<List<Film>> GetFilmsForActorAsync(string actor)` that would do that. Do not try to wrap each entity in its own service, then you have added nothing of real value.

You can also split your services based on functionality and read/write. See [CQRS pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=cqrs+pattern).